# initialization of multiple POST input php

Tags: php, html, post, input, initialization

The issue here is trying with my limited experience to create a section where a user can dynamically edit data already stored. The approach I am using is to create POSTs input in a variable number and initialize them with the already stored values... here is the code

```
<html>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add another Skill" />
<?php
$cars =  ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"];
echo $cars[0];
?>
       <div id="data_fileds">
           <div>
                <div class="content">
                <span>Skill: <input type="text" style="Skill:48px;" name="Skill[]" value= "<?php echo $cars[0];?>" />
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>

  <script>

function add_fields() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('data_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="content"><span>Skill: <input type="text" style="Skill:48px;" name="Skill[]" value="<?php echo $cars[2];?>" />';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
    }
 </script>
</html>
```

I managed in a non-elegant way to initialize the first POST according the first input item... what I am missing is the dynamic allocation of the number of post according the data already stored (in this case the creation of 3 POSTs as per cars array) and the initialization of the POSTs with the car[...i] values...

Anyone can support?
Thanks!!!

---

EDIT

I will try to be more clear, what I would like to obtain is the creation o three "Skill" input filed initialized with the following values

```
Skill[0] --> Volvo
Skill[1] --> BMW
Skill[2] --> Toyota
```

At the moment the program cannot automatically create three "Skill" field but I believe there may be a way forward. So far what I managed to do is to initialize the first field

```
Skill[0] --> Volvo
```

and input a initialization value for any trigged extra Skill input. There is no connection though between the array cars containing the initialization values and the number of input filed "Skills"

Hope this explains.

Comment: read it thrice, not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an input field for every value stored in the *$cars*-array you could use a simple loop:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($cars); $i++): ?>
<div class="content">
    <span>Skill:
        <input type="text" style="Skill:48px;" name="Skill[]" value="<?php echo $cars[$i];?>" />
    </span>
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Yep! I might have try harder by myself... Thanks